# How to change a variable in a generated Makefile in typical gnu-make Linux application build?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm building a typical Linux application with...

```
$ cd /path_to_source
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
$ make
$ make install
```

The configure step of course generates a Makefile. In my case a SWIG_PL_INCLUDES variable is in my Makefile, and I modify it to set the correct value. IOW, I do this...

```
$ cd /path_to_source
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
$ Update SWIG_PL_INCLUDES in generated Makefile
$ make
$ make install
```

I really don't like that. I'm guessing that I can probably modify a file **BEFORE** I run he configure so Makefile is generated with the correct SWIG_PL_INCLUDES value already. So the steps are now...

```
$ cd /path_to_source
$ Update some file to have correct SWIG_PL_INCLUDES
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
$ make
$ make install
```

The file that comes to mind is Makefile.in, and I do see the following line in the Makefile.in file. However, what does the "@SWIG_PL_INCLUDES@" mean? How do I use it to do what I want to do?

```
SWIG_PL_INCLUDES = @SWIG_PL_INCLUDES@
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Unless you explicitly "override" variables, you can directly assign variables:

```
make SWIG_PL_INCLUDES='parameters go here'
```

GNU Make documentation on this behavior is discussed here:
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Overriding.html

As for "@," the second usage may by unnecessary. Documentation suggest that its purpose is limited to suppressing make's echoing of commands. However, I may be unaware of additional functionality.

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Echoing

Edit: See MadScientist's comment for an explanation of the @VARIABLE@ syntax in contex of GNU build system (Autotools).

Comment: Note that the discussion of `@` here is incorrect: the OP is talking about variable values seen in `Makefile.in` which have nothing to do with make's `@` control character.  See my answer below for information on `@` variables in `Makefile.in` files.

Comment: While overriding variables on the command line is arguably better than editing the makefile (at least it will not be overwritten when `configure` is re-run), it's still suboptimal as it requires you to always remember to give that override when you run make. Better would be to convince the `configure` script to use the correct value for `SWIG_PL_INCLUDES` in the first place so no override is necessary.  However for that to be possible the author of the `configure.ac` script needs to have made accommodations for it.

Answer (score 1):

Variables defined in a `Makefile.in` file like `@XXX@` are intended to be replaced by the `configure` script.  Basically, `configure` will examine your system to see what capabilities it has and where they are installed, then it will convert the `Makefile.in` file (that comes with the source you downloaded) into a local `Makefile`, replacing strings with the above form with values based on what `configure` discovered about your system.

If `configure` is not putting the value that you want into your `Makefile`, then usually there are options you can provide to `configure` to tell it where to look for things.

Of course, that depends entirely on the `configure` script you have and what capabilities the person who created it gave to it.  You should run `configure --help` and examine the options available to you carefully, to see if there's one that will let you tell it what path to use for the value of the `SWIG_PL_INCLUDES`.